# date callback function in ignited datatables not working

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

im using ignited datatables library for codeigniter
this is my code:

```
function datatable()
    {
        $this->datatables->select('id,name,created')
            ->unset_column('id')
            ->edit_column('created', '$1',date('Y-m-d H:i:s','created'))
            ->from('categories');

        echo $this->datatables->generate();

    }
```

created is unix timestamp and i want to show date in table.
but when i use callback function like this or in helper it doesn`t work. php warning:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Filename: controllers/categories.php

Line Number: 22
```

created is unix timestamp value in database. when i pass it to date function the database value does not pass to date function. when i var_dump it it shows $1 instead of real value of database. in other functions it works ok. but in date function returns error.

Comment: Try to put timestamp instead of `'created'` in date function.

Comment: Try using a helper function to generate date

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
   $this->datatables->select('id,name,created')
        ->unset_column('id')
        ->edit_column('created', '$1',timestamp('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->from('categories');
```

[Timestamp Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)

Comment: timestamp is not a defined function. did you test it yourself?